# Compatibility Issue with scikit-learn

Tags: python-2.7, scikit-learn

I am trying to use scikit-learn on Python2.7 but import gives error.

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import normalize
import numpy as np
```

This gives following error

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-2-1608d2dbd4a8> in <module>()
      2 from scipy.sparse.linalg import svds
      3 from scipy.sparse import hstack, diags, csr_matrix
----> 4 from sklearn.preprocessing import normalize
      5 import numpy as np
      6 import csv

C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\sklearn\preprocessing\__init__.pyc in <module>()
      4 """
      5 
----> 6 from .data import Binarizer
      7 from .data import KernelCenterer
      8 from .data import MinMaxScaler

C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\sklearn\preprocessing\data.pyc in <module>()
     13 from ..base import BaseEstimator, TransformerMixin
     14 from ..externals import six
---> 15 from ..utils import check_arrays
     16 from ..utils import atleast2d_or_csc
     17 from ..utils import array2d

C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\__init__.pyc in <module>()
      8 import warnings
      9 
---> 10 from .murmurhash import murmurhash3_32
     11 from .validation import (as_float_array, check_arrays, safe_asarray,
     12                          assert_all_finite, array2d, atleast2d_or_csc,

ImportError: cannot import name murmurhash3_32
```

I have installed scikit-learn using `pip install -U scikit-learn`
Can some body help me with this.

Comment: Are you using virtual environments? I'm curious if you installed scikit to a different env. If you're looking to make managing Python environments and packages, I suggest you check out the popular anaconda  Python distribution http://continuum.io/downloads.

Comment: This is most likely due to old files in the sklearn directory. Remove ``C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\sklearn`` and try to install again. If that doesn't work, please give your ``sys.path``.